# Cypress shadow-root inside of shadow-root

Tags: cypress, shadow-root

How do I find the element that is inside of shadow-root which is inside of other shadow-root? I'm new to this and tried .shadow() function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're using Cypress v10, then the configuration is in the file `cypress.config.js` and the format for setting global shadow enabling is

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    ...
  },
  ...
  includeShadowDom: true
})
```

Or use test-specific configuration

```js
it('tests some shadow dom elements', {includeShadowDom: true}, () => {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use `.shadow()` every time. Go to `cypress.json` file and add the following `includeShadowDom: true`.

Now with this added all your `get`, `find` commands will automatically traverse through the shadow dom and reach the element.

```js
cy.get('some-element').should('be.visible')
```